# Error in adding two 4-bit numbers in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to add two 4-bit numbers with full adder. My full adder is working fine, but my two_number_adder module is generating errors. My code is below:

```
    //two bit adder
module three_bit_adder(first_bit, second_bit, carry_in, sum, carry_out);
  input first_bit, second_bit, carry_in;
  output reg sum, carry_out;
  assign sum = (first_bit ^ second_bit) ^ carry_in;
  assign carry_out = (first_bit & second_bit) | (first_bit & carry_in) | (second_bit & carry_in);
endmodule
//add two numbers
module two_number_adder(first_number, second_number, out, carry_out);
  input [3:0] first_number;
  input [3:0] second_number;
  output [3:0] out;
  output reg carry_out;
  reg temp_carry_in, temp_carry_out;
  assign temp_carry_in = 0;
  integer i;
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1)
    begin
      three_bit_adder temp(first_number[i], second_number[i], temp_carry_in, out[i], temp_carry_out);
      assign temp_carry_in = temp_carry_out;
    end
  assign carry_out = temp_carry_out;
endmodule
```

The error says

> genvar is missing for generate loop variable i

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a for-loop to instance a number of modules, that needs to be done in a generate statement. The variable then needs to be a gen var.

Your carry will not work that way. You have to make an vector for the carry bits and connect them correctly. Just as in real hardware you need a 'wire' between the modules.

```
wire [4:0] carry;
genvar i;
generate
  for (i=0; i<4; i=i+1)
     three_bit_adder temp(first_number[i], second_number[i],carry[i], out[i], carry[i+1]);

endgenerate

assign carry[0] = 0;
assign carry_out= carry[4];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. It worked, can you tell one more thing. When exactly to use wire and when to use reg because I am little bit confused in both

Comment: Thanks @dave_59. It is too big a subject to explain here and I could not find a good website. p.s. Have you got a reference for me how to make nice looking links like yours comments? I am looking specific for how to make the "MCVE" link.